# ParseJson.java, Parsing result if NO array name?

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

This is my code:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

/**
 * Created by Belal on 9/22/2015.
 */
public class ParseJSON {
    public static String[] make;
    public static String[] model;
    public static String[] sixMonthRate;

    public static final String JSON_ARRAY = "result";
    public static final String KEY_MAKE = "make";
    public static final String KEY_MODEL = "model";
    public static final String KEY_SIXMONTHRATE = "sixMonthRate";

    private JSONArray vehicle = null;

    private String json;

    public ParseJSON(String json){
        this.json = json;
    }

    protected void parseJSON(){
        JSONObject jsonObject=null;
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
            vehicle = jsonObject.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);

            make = new String[vehicle.length()];
            model = new String[vehicle.length()];
            sixMonthRate = new String[vehicle.length()];

            for(int i=0;i<vehicle.length();i++){
                JSONObject jo = vehicle.getJSONObject(i);
                make[i] = jo.getString(KEY_MAKE);
                model[i] = jo.getString(KEY_MODEL);
                sixMonthRate[i] = jo.getString(KEY_SIXMONTHRATE);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

If I will use [DVLA JSON DATABASE](https://dvlasearch.appspot.com/DvlaSearch?licencePlate=mt09nks&apikey=DvlaSearchDemoAccount) and there is no ARRAY name , how should I change the code to make it work?

Currently if I press button get the data, I have result as app closed.

I'm using this tutorial - [HERE](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-volley-tutorial-to-get-json-from-server/)

Error get

```
03-26 02:49:43.467 23673-23673/com.sandro.openalprsample W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for result
03-26 02:49:43.467 23673-23673/com.sandro.openalprsample W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
03-26 02:49:43.467 23673-23673/com.sandro.openalprsample W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:584)
03-26 02:49:43.467 23673-23673/com.sandro.openalprsample W/System.err:     at com.sandro.openalprsample.ParseJSON.parseJSON(ParseJSON.java:42)
03-26 02:49:43.467 23673-23673/com.sandro.openalprsample W/System.err:     at com.sandro.openalprsample.DVLAresult.showJSON(DVLAresult.java:60)
03-26 02:49:43.467 23673-23673/com.sandro.openalprsample W/System.err:     at com.sandro.openalprsample.DVLAresult.access$000(DVLAresult.java:18)
03-26 02:49:43.472 23673-23673/com.sandro.openalprsample W/System.err:     at com.sandro.openalprsample.DVLAresult$1.onResponse(DVLAresult.java:44)
03-26 02:49:43.472 23673-23673/com.sandro.openalprsample W/System.err:     at com.sandro.openalprsample.DVLAresult$1.onResponse(DVLAresult.java:41)
03-26 02:49:43.472 23673-23673/com.sandro.openalprsample W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
03-26 02:49:43.472 23673-23673/com.sandro.openalprsample W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
03-26 02:49:43.472 23673-23673/com.sandro.openalprsample W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
03-26 02:49:43.472 23673-23673/com.sandro.openalprsample W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
03-26 02:49:43.472 23673-23673/com.sandro.openalprsample W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-26 02:49:43.472 23673-23673/com.sandro.openalprsample W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
03-26 02:49:43.472 23673-23673/com.sandro.openalprsample W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
03-26 02:49:43.472 23673-23673/com.sandro.openalprsample W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-26 02:49:43.472 23673-23673/com.sandro.openalprsample W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
03-26 02:49:43.472 23673-23673/com.sandro.openalprsample W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
03-26 02:49:43.472 23673-23673/com.sandro.openalprsample W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
03-26 02:49:43.472 23673-23673/com.sandro.openalprsample D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
03-26 02:49:43.472 23673-23673/com.sandro.openalprsample E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.sandro.openalprsample, PID: 23673
                                                                           java.lang.NullPointerException: storage == null
                                                                               at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:38)
                                                                               at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:155)
                                                                               at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:128)
                                                                               at com.sandro.openalprsample.CustomList.<init>(CustomList.java:21)
                                                                               at com.sandro.openalprsample.DVLAresult.showJSON(DVLAresult.java:61)
                                                                               at com.sandro.openalprsample.DVLAresult.access$000(DVLAresult.java:18)
                                                                               at com.sandro.openalprsample.DVLAresult$1.onResponse(DVLAresult.java:44)
                                                                               at com.sandro.openalprsample.DVLAresult$1.onResponse(DVLAresult.java:41)
                                                                               at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
                                                                               at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
                                                                               at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of the crash, please?

Comment: If you have array of information then you need to have an array name.. Can you post your json result that you getting

Comment: @malac shah  Updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't follow your code. Base on what you have provide I don't see any JSON Array. As an extension to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36243380/2311047) response I made few modifications and access the data in the JSON object. Here are the additions.

Updates to **MainActivity.java** from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36243380/2311047)

```
HandleJSON obj = new HandleJSON("");
obj.readAndParseJSON(responseOutput.toString());
output.append(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "\nJSON Object... " + System.getProperty("line.separator") + "Make : " + obj.getMake() + "\nModel : " + obj.getModel());
output.append("\nSix Month Rate  : " + obj.getSixMonthRate() + "\nTwelve Month Rate : " + obj.getTwelveMonthRate() + "\nDate of First Registration : " + obj.getDateofFirstRegistrationegistration());
output.append("\nYear of Manufacture : " + obj.getYearOfManufacture() + "\nCylinder Capacity : " + obj.getCylinderCapacity() + "\nCO2 Emmissions : " + obj.getCo2Emissions());
```

**HandleJSON.java**

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;

public class HandleJSON {
    private String make = "make";
    private String model = "model";
    private String sixMonthRate = "sixMonthRate";
    private String twelveMonthRate = "twelveMonthRate";
    private String dateofFirstRegistration = "dateofFirstRegistration";
    private String yearOfManufacture = "yearOfManufacture";
    private String cylinderCapacity = "cylinderCapacity";
    private String co2Emissions= "co2Emissions";

    public HandleJSON(String url) {this.urlString = url;}
    public void setURL(String url){ this.urlString = url;}
    public String getMake() {return make;}
    public String getModel() {return model;}
    public String getSixMonthRate() {return sixMonthRate;}
    public String getTwelveMonthRate() {return twelveMonthRate;}
    public String getDateofFirstRegistrationegistration() {return dateofFirstRegistration;}    
    public String getYearOfManufacture() {return yearOfManufacture;}
    public String getCylinderCapacity() {return cylinderCapacity;}
    public String getCo2Emissions() {return co2Emissions;}

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void readAndParseJSON(String in) {
        try {
            JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(in);
            make = reader.getString("make");
            model = reader.getString("model");
            sixMonthRate = reader.getString("sixMonthRate");
            twelveMonthRate = reader.getString("twelveMonthRate");
            dateofFirstRegistration= reader.getString("dateOfFirstRegistration");
            yearOfManufacture= reader.getString("yearOfManufacture");
            cylinderCapacity= reader.getString("cylinderCapacity");
            co2Emissions= reader.getString("co2Emissions");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Here is the output

[image]

**References:**

- [JSON Formatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)
- [HttpUrlConnection with post request and parameter as Json object android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976240/httpurlconnection-with-post-request-and-parameter-as-json-object-android)
- [ANDROID, Parse JSON data from a web server and display on ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36221795/android-parse-json-data-from-a-web-server-and-display-on-listview)
- [Android weather app: JSON, HTTP and Openweathermap](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/05/build-weather-app-json-http-android.html)
- [Android HTTP Client: GET, POST, Download, Upload, Multipart Request](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/05/android-http-downlod-upload-multipart.html)
- [Android POST request using HttpURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279195/android-post-request-using-httpurlconnection)

Comment: Could I just ask, what should be in HandleJSON  **urlString**

Comment: urlString  in class HandleJSON.java in highlight as red, can't understand what the error is.

Comment: @J.FOG, there is no error, just highlighting the fact that above JSON string can be parsed using the HandleJSON module.

Comment: Error:(20, 13) error: cannot find symbol variable urlString

Comment: as well it do not let me run application with this error((((.

Comment: Solved it. Thanks, I mark your post as answer. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Is DVLA JSON DATABASE supposed to be the contents of JSON_ARRAY?

If so then you should be calling `getJsonObject` instead of `getJsonArray` and then iterate through them as such:

```
for(String key : vehicle.keySet() {
    // Do something with the key and object.
    Object obj = vehicle.get(key);
}
```

If not, I guess I didn't fully understand your question

**Edited**

I'm not sure where you get your `json' value but I'm gonna assume it is the contents of DVLA_JSON_DATABASE

If not, just copy paste the following:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("{\"make\":\"VOLKSWAGEN\",\"model\":\"Tiguan\",\"sixMonthRate\":\"Unknown\",\"twelveMonthRate\":\"Unknown\",\"dateOfFirstRegistration\":\"23 July 2009\",\"yearOfManufacture\":\"2009\",\"cylinderCapacity\":\"1968cc\",\"co2Emissions\":\"167 g/km\",\"fuelType\":\"DIESEL\",\"taxStatus\":\"Taxed and due\",\"colour\":\"SILVER\",\"typeApproval\":\"M1\",\"wheelPlan\":\"2 AXLE RIGID BODY\",\"revenueWeight\":\"Not available\",\"taxDetails\":\"Tax due: 01 April 2016\",\"motDetails\":\"Expires: 21 April 2016\",\"taxed\":true,\"mot\":true}");
```

in place of `json`

Now for some code:

```
try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);

        String make = jsonObject.getString("make");
        String model = jsonObject.getString("model");
        String sixMonthRate = jo.getString("sixMonthRate");
        // Do something with these variables

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

You might've noticed but a JSON consists of a `key:value`.
You simply call `getString(key)` to get a String value.
Similarly you would call 'getInt(key)' to get a Integer value

That's all there is to it!

Comment: No I released that there is NO array name, and I do not understand how to parse the JSON without array name (how to modify it to make it works)

Comment: The stack trace indicates that you don't have a jsonarray, which you don't. A jsonArray is formatted as  'jsonArray':(A,B,C). Take note of the parentheses. Looking at the file, you don't have any parentheses, you actually have only strings and bools. As such, you want to use getString() or getBoolean() for each field. If you're going to learn Android, it would be worthwhile to learn about JSONs since you'll be working with those a lot.(json.org)

Comment: DO you know hot to make it work with out array name? Currently change to JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json); but still no changes

Comment: DO you know the solution, because I'm here do not know how long, braking head about how to solve it.(

Comment: Idea it to make this tutorial https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-volley-tutorial-to-get-json-from-server/ work with this JSON - https://dvlasearch.appspot.com/DvlaSearch?licencePlate=mt09nks&apikey=DvlaSearchDemoAccount

Comment: I didn't go through the tutorial but hopefully the edited answer gives you some insight!